# Strange option in xfce4 menu

Tags: command-line, xfce, menu, session

I've installed a java program from a government website.

I uninstalled it again, but it left a menu icon in my main menu after uninstall. I tried to edit my menu by Menu Editor but got

> This program cannot be seen here.

I searched and found nothing. Google - looking for a command line way. Nothing usable. I cannot find the file which contains this session.

Does anyone know how can I solve?

Answer (score 2):

Apps that appear in these menus will have `.desktop` files in one of these locations

```
/usr/share/applications
/usr/local/share/applications
~/.local/share/applications
```

For example

```
/usr/share/applications/tilda.desktop
```

To clean your desktop menus of a removed app forever, you just need to delete the `.desktop` file.

One possible source of confusion is that sometimes the application will not have the name you expect, for example 'Startup Disk Creator' has the file 'usb-creator-gtk.desktop' which contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Startup Disk Creator
```

...and some more stuff. You can see that you can check you've found the right one by reading the file and looking at the `Name=...` line

If the application has a distinctive name, you might want to use a short way of finding & deleting its `.desktop` file (replace `pesky` with the name of the application you want to get rid of the menu item for):

```
sudo updatedb
locate -e --regex 'applications/.*pesky.*\.desktop' | xargs -p sudo rm
```

(The `-p` makes `xargs` ask for confirmation before executing `sudo rm` on the file(s) you found, so you can check them first if unsure)